# Why does the Ubuntu Server installer ask for both a subnet and IP address?

Tags: server, ip, subnet

When installing a new Ubuntu server instance, the installer asks for a subnet in CIDR notation and then it asks for an IP address without CIDR notation.

Why can't I just specify the IP address in CIDR notation? Wouldn't that include all of the necessary information? I seem to always mess up the subnet in CIDR notation during installation because I don't use that method anywhere else.

Comment: What are you seeking?

Comment: @WU-TANG The human search for truth and Minimum Description Length is never ending.

Comment: @WU-TANG I want to understand the logic behind asking for two piece of redundant information. This always seems to slow me down when working on a new installation.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically when entering the subnet address in CIDR notation it would be
sufficient information to enter

```
<your IP address>/<mask>
```

rather than

```
<your IP address & ^<mask>>/<mask>
```

although perhaps Ubuntu insists on the latter.  Have you tried it?

Comment: I would agree "<your IP address>/<mask>" should be enough information, there's no reason that we need to explicitly spell out the subnet.

Comment: You've essentially confirmed that the information is redundant. However, why would the installer be asking for redundant information?

Comment: Right - why not just ask for the CIDR - i.e., the number of bits for the prefix? One guess would be that it was slightly easier for the programmer, because the was already a routine for reading in standard CIDR notation (addr/mask).  Another is that it follows standard precedent  - in fact I can't recall seeing anyplace that asked just CIDR suffix without the net address too (although I have found address can contain random insignificant bits without generating more than a warnring, e.g., it works in UFW with just a warning).

Comment: Edit: above should be "why not just ask for the CIDR suffix, "